# SSIS importing specific rows from flat file

Tags: ssis

my requirement was to import only specific amount of data from a flat file . how would I get  all the rows between first and last occurrence of a Specific row from a flat file in SSIS.

For example if you see below data

```
TX
CA
IN
NY
IN
IL
NJ
IN
WA
OH 
IN
AZ
NV
```

I would need my output like below . Rows between first and last occurrence of `IN`

```
IN
NY
IN
IL
NJ
IN
WA
OH 
IN
```

Answer (score 0):

@Navya-You can first import the data into temp table.
Once data has be imported into table,filter the column and take required data and again generate a flat file from the same.
That's the easiest method you can try.